# Python selenium web driver not scrolling

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to fetch all the google reviews by using python web scrapping and selenium. I am able to fetch 8 reviews and its getting repeated for three times(8*3=24), but the problem is that the driver is not able to scroll into the review section element. I already tried "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight" , "arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true), element" and div element containing text of last review but nothing worked. Below is the code and I have commented out the scrolling part because of error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException

def scrape_google_reviews(url):
    # Set up Chrome WebDriver
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run in headless mode, i.e., without opening browser window
    chromedriver_path = 'C:/Users/Downloads/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver.exe'  # Specify path to chromedriver executable
    service = Service(chromedriver_path)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

    # Load the Google Maps URL
    driver.get(url)

    # Wait for the reviews to load
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "m6QErb")))
    except TimeoutException as e:
        print("Timeout occurred while waiting for reviews to load:", e)
        driver.quit()
        return None
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred while waiting for reviews to load:", e)
        driver.quit()
        return None

    # Scroll the page to load more reviews 1:
    # for _ in range(5):
    #     try:
        #     #driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        #     element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[8]/div[9]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]")
        #     driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", element);
            
        #     WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "m6QErb")))
        # except TimeoutException as e:
        #     print("Timeout occurred while scrolling the page:", e)
        # except Exception as e:
        #     print("An error occurred while scrolling the page:", e)

    # Scroll the page to load more reviews 2:
    # for _ in range(5):
    #     try:
    #         driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    #         WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "m6QErb")))
    #     except TimeoutException as e:
    #         print("Timeout occurred while scrolling the page:", e)
    #     except Exception as e:
    #         print("An error occurred while scrolling the page:", e)
    
    # Scroll to the element containing the specified text 3:
    # def scroll_to_element_with_text(driver, text):
    #     element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f'//div[contains(text(), "{text}")]')))
    #     driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
    
    # # Example usage
    # scroll_to_element_with_text(driver, "Akanksha Mamidi")

    # Extract review elements
    parent_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "m6QErb")

    # Extract review details
    reviews = []
    for parent_element in parent_elements:
        try:
            review_elements = parent_element.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "jftiEf")
            for review_element in review_elements:
                reviewer_name = get_reviewer_name(review_element)
                reviews.append({"reviewer_name": reviewer_name})
        except NoSuchElementException as e:
            print("Failed to extract review elements:", e)

    # Close the WebDriver
    driver.quit()

    return reviews

def get_reviewer_name(review_element):
    # Traverse through descendant div elements until we find the target div with class="d4r55"
    current_element = review_element
    while True:
        try:
            reviewer_name = current_element.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "d4r55").text
            return reviewer_name
        except NoSuchElementException:
            # If target div is not found, move to the next descendant div
            try:
                current_element = current_element.find_element(By.XPATH, "./div")
            except NoSuchElementException:
                # If there are no more descendant div elements, return "N/A"
                return "N/A"

# Example usage
url = "https://www.google.com/maps/place/D2F+Down+To+Food/@18.5481413,73.915032,17.25z/data=!3m1!5s0x3bc2c16de1528699:0xa02a4b8382ddc942!4m8!3m7!1s0x3bc2c192c1367d85:0xd471b3b584c04e4b!8m2!3d18.5482359!4d73.9181862!9m1!1b1!16s%2Fg%2F11kj3mpnb2?entry=ttu"
reviews = scrape_google_reviews(url)
if reviews:
    for i, review in enumerate(reviews, 1):
        print(f"Review {i}:")
        print(f"Reviewer Name: {review['reviewer_name']}")
        print()
else:
    print("Failed to scrape reviews.")
```

My chrome version is 122.0.6261.113 and I have downloaded chromedriver.exe from here: https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/122.0.6261.128/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip